# How to reduce size of an empty android app under 1mb

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The app is initial empty project which make with android studio latest and only one main activity.

currently I can get 1.2 mb total but I need it under 1 mb.

what can be done to reduce the size?

I have tried filter arm, x86 libraries but still same, also tried minify but still not under 1 mb.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any dependencies?

Comment: At a minimum you'll probably need to enable use of ProGuard.....then, as @GiovanniTerlingen mentioned you'll need to check your dependencies (also check transitive ones as well).

Comment: https://fractalwrench.co.uk/posts/playing-apk-golf-how-low-can-an-android-app-go/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have tried this before, my blank applications size was `1500kb`, to reduce the size

- i just `removed appCompact and constraintLayout dependencies` from the gradle
- then `cleared the app theme` from the styles and removed it from manifest as well.

the end result was that my apk size was `74 kb`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the appcompat support library, it adds extra size to the apk.

It is generally added as a dependency by default. Remove it or look for other dependencies.

The app size will also be slightly reduced if you minify the apk. Search for it in Google or refer to @sarath's answer.

Answer (score 1):

add this lines in build.gradle

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

for more details check this link https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size.html

Answer (score 0):

Did not try this but maybe this helps you!

- appcompat-v7 will add 1MB to your APK, and design should add 300KB, You do not have to use appcompat-v7 so you can remove it.
- In Android Studio 2.2.3, setting up a new project, choosing the Empty
  Activity template, and unchecking the "Backwards compatibility"
  the checkbox will skip appcompat-v7
- You can use Build > Analyze APK in Android Studio 2.2+ to see how big
  your actual APK is and where space is going.